# BGE - Could not open marshal file Error

Tags: game-engine

Trying to export a list of features for some objects from a csv file to the GlobalDist in BGE (Blender 2.78) but the Python Console returns the following error : "Warning : could not open marshal file" and the .bgeconfig is not created.

Does someone have an idea ?

thanks a lot,

this is the code I lunched in internal text :

```
import bge, csv

from bge import logic

gd=bge.logic.globalDict

db=csv.reader(open(logic.expandPath("//")+"/db_weapons.csv","r"),delimiter=",")

is_header=True

temp_dict={}

for row in db:

if is_header:
    header=row
    is_header=False
else: 
    for col in range (1,len(row)):
        temp_dict[header[col]]=row[col]
    gd[row[0]]=temp_dict

print (gd)

logic.saveGlobalDict()
```

Comment: The configuration of the bgeconfig file moight be wrong. The error message will appear when the file could not be opened,

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you know how to configurate it ? i though it'd have been created autoaticaly with the command logic.saveGlobalDict()

Comment: I never worked with it. I just looked at the source code. The message will be printed when the file could not be opened. That way the message is a bit misleading.